# Extension of conformal mapping ouside unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

Suppose I have a conformal mapping $f:D\to \Omega$ which takes a unit disc to a connected blob $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$. There should exist a conformal mapping $g:\mathbb{C}\setminus D\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$  (this is true right?)

My question is that, is there any theorem/formula can relate $g$ to $f$ other than they have to agree on the boundary $\partial \Omega$?

What about the mapping $h: D\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657530/analytic-continuation-of-the-bounded-holomorphic-function

Comment: So it basically says that, suppose we have $f$, if $g$ exists (which his guaranteed by the post you linked?), then $g$ must be the analytic continuation of $f$ outside the disc which is also unique (assuming we have a "good" boundary curve)

Comment: Ahlfors is also assuming that $f^{-1}:\Omega\to D$ is holomorphic, and I fear that hypothesis cannot be dropped.

Comment: I thought this is guaranteed by Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: It depends: is $D$ the *open* unit disk?

Comment: I think so. I m interested in the map that maps a sligtly deformed circle or a deformed flat interface to the unit circle or the real line.